# Loop over query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

*Drupal 7 DB select*

**Here I am getting a array:**

---

```
Array ( [71] => adad [85] => erer )
```

---

**How can I loop the above array in this query below?**

```
function get values($array){
 $q =  db_select('node', 'n');
  $q->join('ab', 'f', 'n.nid = f.entity_id');
  $rooms_data = $q->condition('n.type', 'book');
if($room_selected!=null)
{
  $rooms_data = $q->condition('n.nid', $array); **//assumption//**
}
   $rooms_data = $q->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
    ->fields('f', array('feesid'))
    ->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC')
    ->execute();
}
```

Assuming something like:

```
->wherein($array as $a)
{
$q->condition('n.nid',$a['value']);
}
```

Comment: You can use foreach loop

Comment: `$array` contains something like `[['value'=>1],['value'=>2],...]`? That's it? Or just `Array ( [71] => adad [85] => erer )`?

Comment: @Syscall like this -> [['value'=>1],['value'=>2],...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `"IN"` as `$operator` of [`SelectQuery::condition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Acondition/7.x), and use an array of scalar values as `$value`. To do this, you could use [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) to extract these values:

```
function get_values($array, $room_selected) {
    $q =  db_select('node', 'n');
    $q->join('ab', 'f', 'n.nid = f.entity_id');
    $q->condition('n.type', 'book');
    if ($room_selected != null)
    {
        $values = array_column($array, 'value') ;
        $q->condition('n.nid', $values, 'IN') ;
    }
    $rooms_data = $q->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
        ->fields('f', array('feesid'))
        ->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC')
        ->execute();
}
```

Comment: i forgot to add in the post.